# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'TestSpider'

Tags: python, python-unittest

I am trying to use `unittest` from python, but I get the following error: `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'TestSpider'` My test code is as follows

```
import unittest

from spiders.eshopsite import EshopsiteSpider

### Unit Test for the EshopsiteSpider class

class TestSpider(unittest.TestCase):

    def testExtractAnchor(self):
        testArray = [u'/test1', u'/test1/test2', u'test2']
        testObj = EshopsiteSpider()
        testOutputArray = testObjextractAnchors(testArray)
        self.assertEqual(len(testArray), len(testOutputArray))
        index = 0
        ### A loop is needed to compare each element in the
        ### arrays. To assert if they are equal
        while index < len(testOutputArray):
            varOne = testOutputArray[index]
            varTwo = testArray[index].encode('utf8')[1:]
            self.assertEqual(varOne, varTwo)
            index = index + 1



if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

and my folder structure:

[image]

And the full stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/runpy.py", line 170, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/unittest/__main__.py", line 18, in <module>
    main(module=None)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/unittest/main.py", line 92, in __init__
    self.parseArgs(argv)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/unittest/main.py", line 139, in parseArgs
    self.createTests()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/unittest/main.py", line 146, in createTests
    self.module)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/unittest/loader.py", line 146, in loadTestsFromNames
    suites = [self.loadTestsFromName(name, module) for name in names]
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/unittest/loader.py", line 146, in <listcomp>
    suites = [self.loadTestsFromName(name, module) for name in names]
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/unittest/loader.py", line 114, in loadTestsFromName
    parent, obj = obj, getattr(obj, part)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'TestSpider'
```

To execute the test, I used the following command: `python3 -m unittest tests/TestSpider`

I cannot figure out what is wrong based on other tests. Even if I comment out everything in the test function, except the very first statement, I get the same error.

I hope someone can point me in the right direction or help with a solution.

\Lars

Comment: I tried that: `import unittest

class TestSpider(unittest.TestCase):
    def testExtractAnchor(self):
        print("Hello world")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()` and it worked. Does it work for you?

Comment: Are you sure there are no other modules named `tests` installed? `IPython` provides one, for example. Check that `import tests;print(tests.__file__)` actually points to your content.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Also, maybe it was a typo in this question, but your command is referencing `test/TestSpider`, but your screenshot is showing folder `tests`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre yes that code works.

Comment: @idjaw that is a typo

Comment: @MisterMiyagi pretty sure `ImportError: No module named 'tests'`

Comment: I was expecting user-made `unittest.py` but today it's a dirname with `__init__.py` instead :) good find all! You should _never_ call your modules or directories `test` or `tests` because it conflicts with ... well, a lot of stuff :)

Comment: I tried to rename the dir to `aiiihooo` still smae error :/

Comment: But thanks moving the test file to the `root` folder fixed the problem :/